# Leave view controller, quit game

Tags: ios, class, memory-management

I am making a game and when the user presses a button in the menu VC, the game VC opens and in the `viewDidLoad` I have method which setups the game (ergo, creates an instance of the `Game` class); creates a deck of cards, creates players, add cards to players, etc. Now I want the possibility to cancel/ quit the game and I have a button for that, obviously. When I press that button the menu VC is shown again, but the `Game` class still exists. The Ai players are still even playing, as I can see in my log.

My question is how I can cancel the game and "deallocate" the `Game` class and clear the players array, clear the deck of cards, etc. As far as I know I cannot "deallocate" the objects, because that is not allowed in ARC.

I know how to change views, but just need a way to quit the game.

A bit more information about the `Game` class;

```
@implementation Game

{
int _activePlayerPosition;
NSArray *activePlayersArray;
//Player *activePlayer;

}

+(Game *) game {
static Game *game = nil;
if(game == nil) {
    game = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
}
return game;
}

-(id) init {
if((self = [super init])){

}
return self;
}

-(void) setupGame {
NSLog(@"setup game");
_deckCard = [[DeckCard alloc]init];
_tableCard = [[TableCard alloc]init];
_players = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];
_deckCards = _deckCard.cardsInDeck;
_tableCards = _tableCard.cardsOnTable;

//If game is single player, start single player game.
if([Game game].isSinglePlayerGame) {
    [self startSinglePlayerGame];
}

_activePlayerId = 0;

//Check playabality of all playercards in Game.
NSArray *playersArray = [[[Game game] players] allKeys];
for(int x = 0; x <[playersArray count];x++){
    id key = [playersArray objectAtIndex:x];
    id player = [[[Game game] players] objectForKey:key];
    [player isPlayerAllowedToPlay];
}
}
```

So an instance of the `Game` class is used in the gameViewController, with all other objects that were created (arrays, players, etc.).

So how do I quit a game?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to set your Game class to nil?

Comment: We need to know how you are storing your Game object. Your question is missing critical information.

Comment: @CrimsonChris Fair enough, I edited my question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like you are using a singleton. You need to nil out that static instance of your game. To do that, you need to move the declaration outside of that method and provide a method that assigns it to nil.

Comment: Indeed, as CrimsonChris says, the previous instance continues to exist... because you've written your code to go specifically out of its way to ensure that the previous instance continues to exist. That's something you've done, on purpose.

Comment: Thanks to @CrimsonChris and Tommy Your comments have put me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thans to CrimsonChris and Tommy, who have put me on the right path. I changed the singleton class like below and added a method the reset to nil.

```
static Game *game = nil;

+(Game *) game {
if(game == nil) {
    game = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
}
return game;
}

+ (void)resetGame {
game = nil;
}
```

Thanks Guys!